# Adding ad to the bottom of linearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

I don't know how to put a view to the bottom of linearLayout. I tryed using layout_gravity="bottom", but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background_register_login"
    tools:context="com.mcd.fantaleghe.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... you could solve this problem in several ways, but the easiest are:

1- Change your LinearLayout to FrameLayout and erase the line `android:orientation="vertical"`

2- Add this to your LinearLayout `android:gravity="bottom"`

3- You could follow this [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) and forget about including the adview in the xml because in the tutorial they include it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I used to always use `LinearLayout` because it is so simple, but you should really consider using a `RealtiveLayout` to save yourself a lot of headaches.

In a `RelativeLayout` you could set `layout_alignParentBottom=true` or just `layout_alignBelow=@+id/thingToBeBelow` and the ad will be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LinearLayout` as parent , You need to create a container layout to fill the other area above  the `AdView` like this. You can add all your other child views inside the container layout or leave it empty.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/welcomeAdView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Another , way is to use `RelativeLayout` as parent and place the `AdView` to parent `bottom`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```